Is this a reasonable way to transform simple MSE loss function to weighted MSE for neural networks?
The idea is tested on a dataset with a clear outlier (see picture below)
data = {0. -> {0., 1.}, 0.2 -> {0.2, 1.3313}, 0.4 -> {0.4, 1.12215}, 
   0.6 -> {0.6, 1.74427}, 0.8 -> {0.8, 2.10747}, 1. -> {1., 2.08546}, 
   1.2 -> {1.2, 2.11952}, 1.4 -> {1.4, 2.43156}, 
   1.6 -> {1.6, 2.90507}, 1.8 -> {1.8, 2.92229}, 2. -> {2., 3.69933}, 
   2.2 -> {2.2, 2.88064}, 2.4 -> {2.4, 4.13182}, 
   2.6 -> {2.6, 3.48614}, 2.8 -> {2.8, 5.00537}, 3. -> {3., 4.08107}, 
   3.1 -> {3.1, 9.2469}, 3.2 -> {3.2, 4.61768}, 3.4 -> {3.4, 4.7964}, 
   3.6 -> {3.6, 5.26735}, 3.8 -> {3.8, 5.54625}, 4. -> {4., 5.71246}, 
   4.2 -> {4.2, 6.17115}, 4.4 -> {4.4, 6.97052}, 
   4.6 -> {4.6, 7.64505}, 4.8 -> {4.8, 7.2061}, 5. -> {5., 8.18249}};

deep = NetChain[{100, LinearLayer[100], Tanh, 2}]; wGraph = 
 NetGraph[<|"net" -> deep, "loss" -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[], 
   "times" -> ThreadingLayer[Times]|>, {"net" -> 
    "loss", {NetPort["Weight"], "loss"} -> 
    "times" -> NetPort["WeightedLoss"]}];
dataset := <|"Input" -> data[[All, 1]], "Target" -> data[[All, 2]], 
   "Weight" -> weight|>;

finalplot := 
 With[{result = 
    NetTrain[wGraph, dataset, LossFunction -> "WeightedLoss", 
     MaxTrainingRounds -> 5000, BatchSize -> 200]}, 
  final = NetExtract[result, "net"]; 
  Show[ListPlot[{Flatten[Table[final@{x}, {x, 0., 5., 0.2}], 1], 
     data[[All, 2]][[All, 1 ;; 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}]]]

weight = Table[0.1, Length[data]]; finalplot

This produces

The idea continues to be explored by looking at  effect of a small weight for the outlier
weight = 
 ReplacePart[Table[0.1, Length[data]], 17 -> 0.000001]; finalplot

This produces

The bump in the regression caused by the outlier dissappeared.
Finally we look at the effect of a big weight for the outlier
weight = ReplacePart[Table[0.1, Length[data]], 17 -> 40.]; finalplot

This produces

The bump is accentuated.
The effect is aligned with the expectation, is the new loss being used at every training step? Improvemente tips on this code or the implementation of custom loss functions in Mathematica are welcome.

Yes, that's a reasonable way to add weights to the data points during training.
